Key lengths issues with aes decrypt in powershell
I'm having troubles in decrypting a string (password) with a powershell 5.x script.
Here is my script:
function ConvertTo-ByteArray {
    param (
        [string]$InputString
    )
    if ($InputString -match "^[0-9A-Fa-f]+$") {
        # Se la stringa è esadecimale, converti in byte array
        return [System.Convert]::FromHexString($InputString)
    } else {
        # Altrimenti, usa la codifica UTF8
        return [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($InputString)
    }
}


$masterkey = "26LR8b1xrRc4NFz/vdpHGi50mXqoNoC+8V6QsoUyF9E="
$IV        = "3+NA+JlYIQGPTHsQX4dR+A=="
$EncPwd    = "Jj9aiTm+IQp9y4PpTilaYHACgYk4lD/qhDyGxWU6RNc="

$keyBytes = ConvertTo-ByteArray -InputString $masterkey
$ivBytes = ConvertTo-ByteArray -InputString $IV

Write-Host "Masterkey bytes: " $keyBytes
Write-Host "Initial Vector bytes: " $ivBytes 

# Decodifica la stringa Base64 in byte array
$encryptedBytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($EncPwd)

# Crea l'oggetto AES
$aes = [System.Security.Cryptography.Aes]::Create()
$aes.Key = $keyBytes
$aes.IV = $ivBytes
$aes.Padding = "PKCS7"
#exit

# Crea il decryptor e decripta i dati
$decryptor = $aes.CreateDecryptor()
$plainBytes = $decryptor.TransformFinalBlock($encryptedBytes, 0, $encryptedBytes.Length)

# Converti i byte decriptati in una stringa leggibile
$plainText = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($plainBytes)

# Output del testo decriptato
Write-Output $plainText

And here is the error I get:
Exception setting "Key": "The specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm."
At E:\deploy\test\decript-test.ps1:85 char:1
+ $aes.Key = $keyBytes
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
 
Exception setting "IV": "Specified initialization vector (IV) does not match the block size for this algorithm."
At E:\deploy\test\decript-test.ps1:86 char:1
+ $aes.IV = $ivBytes
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
 
Exception calling "CreateDecryptor" with "0" argument(s): "Decrypting a value requires that a key be set on the algorithm 
object."
At E:\deploy\test\decript-test.ps1:91 char:1
+ $decryptor = $aes.CreateDecryptor()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CryptographicException
 
Exception calling "TransformFinalBlock" with "3" argument(s): "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed."
At E:\deploy\test\decript-test.ps1:92 char:1
+ $plainBytes = $decryptor.TransformFinalBlock($encryptedBytes, 0, $enc ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CryptographicException
 
Exception calling "GetString" with "1" argument(s): "Array cannot be null.
Parameter name: bytes"
At E:\deploy\test\decript-test.ps1:95 char:1
+ $plainText = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($plainBytes)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException

According to what I read here and there (and from the error message of course) the problem should be the key/IV length, but I haven't understood how long they must really be.
Here are the encryption specifics I got for this procedure:

BlockSize: 128 FeedbackSize: 128 KeySize: 256 bit Mode: 1 CBC Padding:
2 PKCS#7 Initialization vector (iv) derived randomly from masterkey:
16 byte Salt size: 8 byte Masterkey: 32 byte

Does anyone have any hint?
Thanks and regards,
Alessandro.

IV size has to be $aes.BlockSize / 8 bits and the valid keysizes you can find them in $aes.LegalKeySizes. you can use [System.Collections.BitArray]::new(...).Count for testing, right now your IV has 192 and key has 352 (both invalid)

You need to base64 decode both $masterkey and $IV.

How was Jj9aiTm+IQp9y4PpTilaYHACgYk4lD/qhDyGxWU6RNc= encrypted ? Do you have that implementation ? Even after b64 decoding your Key and IV the padding is invalid

There is something wrong with your data, s. CyberChef. Post consistent data or your encryption code.

@President James K. Polk : I tried to [System.Convert]::FromBase64String() IV and master key and I get (according to what I understood) correct sizes of IV and MK (respectively 16 and 32 bytes). They seems to me in line with the specifics I posted. However now I get another error Exception calling "TransformFinalBlock" with "3" argument(s): "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed."

@Santiago , Topaco I don't have the encryption script, I just receive masterkey, enc password and IV. What I know however is that the decrypted string should be: 388LpyYazvTwoEWvgS3!

@AlessandroFolloni: Now you're encountering the problem Topaco pointed out: inconsistent data. I'm sure Topaco tried all the options available in CyberChef to see if some combination of mode and padding could produce something valid that looks like a password, but nothing worked.

@President : I'm not really familiar with encryption so it took me a while to understand your suggestions. I double checked Topaco suggestion with a bash script I'm sure is correct and it fails (I did that just for my understandings). So after converting correcty IV and masterkey my script runs well (when keys are correct of course). Thanks all
